# Flash kiosk touch app - if nothing happens go to homepage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a simple touchscreen app with flash. When users doesn't use it for 1 or 2 minutes I would like that the movie will automatically go back to the homepage link. How to reach that?

Is there any actionscript that if a mouse doesn't move for 2 minutes the movie will go to a link or it will rewind?

Thank you!

SOLVED:
AS2.0

```
 // main timeline code
 timeout = 5000;

 this.onMouseMove = function(){
 clearInterval(ID);
 ID = setInterval(action, timeout);
 trace("interaction");
 };

 function action(){
 clearInterval(ID);
 trace("no interaction for 5 seconds");
 // go to end frame
 };
```

Comment: You can use a [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) object to handle this. Basically, set a Timer to fire after 1 or 2 minutes, whatever, you want, when that Timer fires, it executes whatever code you want, in this case, you want to go back to the homepage link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is static class I wrote for a kiosk application I made many years ago.  You just pass in a reference to the main stage,  a function to reset the program,  and a dialog box function (you could easily take out that part of the code if you don't want the dialog).

```
TimeoutManager.init(stage, myResetFunction, myDialogBoxFunction);
```

You could enable or disable it anytime with:  `TimeoutManager.kioskTimeoutEnabled = false;`

Let me know if you have any questions about it, it's fairly well commented.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.clearTimeout;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    /**
     * Manages the Kiosk session timeout functionality
     * @LDMS
     */
    public class TimeoutManager
    {


        //KioskTimeout Vars
        private static var kioskTimeoutEnabled_ :Boolean = false;
        private static var kioskTimeoutTimer    :Timer  = new Timer(3000, 1);
        private static var kioskTimeout         :uint;

        private static var timeoutCountdownTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

        private static var stage                :Stage;

        public static var defaultTime           :int = 120000;  //2 minutes - amount of inactivity before the "are you still there" message comes up.
        public static var dialogTime            :int = 30000;   //30 seconds - amount of time to wait for the user to click the "are you still there" message before reseting the applicaiton

        public static var resetFunction :Function; //the function to call to reset the application
        public static var dialogFunction:Function; //the function to call to show a dialog box - passes tittle & text as two parameters to the method.

        public static function init(mainStage:Stage, resetFunction_:Function, dialogFunction_:Function):void {
            stage = mainStage;
            resetFunction = resetFunction_;
            dialogFunction = dialogFunction_;

            kioskTimeoutTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeoutKiosk, false, 0, true);
            kioskTimeoutEnabled = true;

            timeoutCountdownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdownTick, false, 0, true);
        }

        /**
         * Enable or Disable the Kiosk reset timeout feature
         */
        public static function set kioskTimeoutEnabled(val:Boolean):void
        {

            kioskTimeoutEnabled_ = val;
            if (val) {
                setKioskTimeout();
                try {   stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, kioskTimeoutReset, false, 0, true);   } catch (e:Error) { trace(e.toString()); };
            } else {
                cancelKioskTimeout();
                try {   stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, kioskTimeoutReset, false); } catch (e:Error) { trace(e.toString()); };
            };
        }

        public static function get kioskTimeoutEnabled():Boolean {  return kioskTimeoutEnabled_;    };

        /**
         * Resets the timeout period for the kiosk reset timeout feature - called on a global mouse_down event.
         * @param   e - unused mouse_down event
         */
        public static function kioskTimeoutReset(e:Event = null):void {
            cancelKioskTimeout();
            setKioskTimeout();
        }

        /**
         * used to cancel the kiosk timeout period temporarily
         */
        public static function cancelKioskTimeout():void {
            kioskTimeoutTimer.reset();
        }

        /**
         * Set or reset the time (in milliseconds) before the kiosk times out.
         * @param   overrideTime - if not 0 (default), sets a temporary new time (in milliseconds) before the kiosk times out.
         */
        public static function setKioskTimeout(overrideTime:Number = 0):void {
            if(!kioskTimeoutEnabled) return;

            try {   cancelKioskTimeout();   } catch (e:Error) { };

            var time:Number =   (overrideTime > 0)  ?   overrideTime    :   defaultTime;

            kioskTimeoutTimer.delay = time;
            kioskTimeoutTimer.start();
        }

        /**
         * after the set inactivity period passes, this function is called to let the user know the kiosk is about to reset giving them a chance to keep their session alive
         */
        private static function timeoutKiosk(e:Event = null):void {
            dialogFunction("Are you still there?", "Reset in " + String(Preferences.kioskTimeout_dialogTime / 1000) + " seconds");

            timeoutCountdownTimer.start();

            kioskTimeout = setTimeout(goReset, dialogTime);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clearKioskTimeout2,false,0,true);
        }

        protected static function countdownTick(e:TimerEvent):void {
            dialogFunction("Are you still there?", "Reset in " + String((Preferences.kioskTimeout_dialogTime / 1000) - timeoutCountdownTimer.currentCount) + " seconds");
        }

        /**
         * Cancels the timeout prompt timeout
         * @param   e - unused mouse event
         */
        private static function clearKioskTimeout2(e:Event = null):void {
            try {
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clearKioskTimeout2,false);
            }catch (e:Error) { trace(e.toString()); };

            clearTimeout(kioskTimeout);
            timeoutCountdownTimer.reset();
        }

        private static function goReset(e:Event = null):void {
            timeoutCountdownTimer.reset();
            resetFunction();
        }
    }

}
```